# NativeScript token interceptor failed to find

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript, native

I have a NativeScript app that app is run my Android. When I build for android and install Apk, I have an error like this:

> Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "./_interceptors/token.interceptor", relative to app/app/

I changed `./_interceptors/token.interceptor` to `../app/_interceptors/token.interceptor` or `"~/app/_interceptors/token.interceptor`. Sometimes, absolutely randomly, problem solved and app is works so well.

I tried reinstall `node_modules`, `platforms` but still I can't fix this issue.

How can I build clean Apk?

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Are you using Angular for development? Does this happen with `--bundle` option?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Angular. How can I use `--bundle` ?

Comment: Just pass in the `--bundle` parameter in your `tns run` command. Are you using Windows? Did you try eliminating `_` in the folder name (`_interceptors`)?